How can we add a File Link to the Record in Salesforce user interface?
Looks like we can add a file link using Dataloader or sf data upsert bulk command by populating ContentUrl field but we can't really do the same thing in the User interface. Is this a platform limitation? I cannot find any kind of information on this.
I am looking for the standard functionality. I understand we could achieve this by custom UI.
